# Why do I sometimes see a construction like "is string {variable}"

Tags: c#

In code samples I sometimes find code that looks similar to this:

```
        var foo = "Me";
        if ({some condition} && foo is string bar)
        {
             //bar has now the value "Me"
        }
```

It seems that I first declare a new variable "foo" and in the next step I create a second variable "bar" that gets the value of foo.
This code works, but I never read in the docs about a construction like "foo is string bar".

1. Where can I find this in the documentation?
2. In which cases does this make sense? I would just use "foo" without re-declaring a new variable with "bar".

One example where it is used is [here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/12/24/multitenant-azure-ad-issuer-validation-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: It's called pattern matching.

Comment: [pattern matching with `is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi I disagree with that.

Comment: Thanks - my question is already answered :)

Comment: `In which cases does this make sense?` When `foo` is `object` (or something like an interface), not **already** a specific type (like `string`).

Comment: @bolkay, it's okay, it was just an opinion. And you're allowed to be wrong XD